# How do I inflate a second XML layout on top of another from an onClickListener?

Tags: android, xml, fragment, onclicklistener

How do I inflate a second XML layout from an onClickListener?
While building an android app, I've come across the need to inflate a new layout without actually moving from the original fragment(For user entry data loss reasons). I would love to set all this up using an alertDialog, but alertDialog does not allow for radioGroups and I have at least 4 groups that I need to prompt the User with. The R XML resource referenced is a constraintLayout.

```
binding.promptMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                View defectMenu = View.inflate(getContext(),R.layout.promptMenu, null);
                WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
                );

                WindowManager windowManager = ((WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE));
                windowManager.addView(defectMenu, layoutParams);

               }
        });
```

Am I going about this in the correct way? Or is there an easier way to do this that I'm not seeing?
Thanks to all who answer.

Comment: You can use an AlertDialog with a custom layout: https://suragch.medium.com/creating-a-custom-alertdialog-bae919d2efa5 and you  can also use a DialogFragment to create your own dialog.